# How I posting to FB fanpage post from WP automatically?

Tags: mysql, facebook, wordpress

I need posting to facebook fanpage from my wordpress auction site the new auctions (posts )automatically. What is my possibilites? Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this wery simple use the wordpress plugin:
[NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

- Authorize your user with the manage_pages and publish_actions permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1
  (you can also just generate an access token with the API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
- Get an Extended Page Access Token (lasting forever), for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/
- Post to the page by using the `/page-id/feed` endpoint of the Facebook API, with that Extended Page Token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed

For further information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs